# Does Spring Boot 2 Actuator work in external Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've got a Spring Boot 2 app that initially used the embedded Tomcat to run. Having **Actuator** included in the project, I could do

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/health'
```

and get a response.

Now I've moved the app into a WAR file to be deployed into an external Tomcat (8.2.23), and the actuator endpoint is no longer found. The app itself still works, but I can't get to the exposed actuator endpoints.

Is this a known bug ('feature'?), or is there a special configuration needed? I'm not currently trying to define any new actuator endpoints. I also don't have security included.

Comment: Sigh. My bad. Discovered that in the external deployment, the application name has to precede **actuator**!

Comment: Worth actually posting a proper answer about it...

Comment: If the application is not deployed in the root Tomcat context but in its own context, it is totally expected as any resource of the application be available from its context.

Comment: @Makoto Couldn't post an answer at the time. Too soon after posting the question when I added the comment. So selecting the answer that was submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploying in external tomcat, all rest end points of your application will now become `http://localhost:8080/{Name of war file}/actual-end-point`

Comment: Still not working. Will there be any other solution?